# How to access the request body in an API route in next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am passing `body` to the request but it is always being received as null.

Here is my code:

```js
import { NextResponse,NextRequest } from "next/server";


// Handles GET requests to /api
export async function GET(request: NextRequest) {
  // ...
  return NextResponse.json({ message: "Hello World" });
}

// Handles POST requests to /api
export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const theURL = request.body
  return NextResponse.json({ message: theURL});
}
```

The output of `{ message: theURL}` is always `{ message: ""}` despite I have double checked from the client side that body is being sent.

Comment: what do you post to the endpoint?

Comment: Have you tried replacing const theURL = request.body with const theURL= await request.json();

Answer (score 0):

The [NextRequest](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server#nextrequest) type comes with three distinct methods to parse and access the request body. There are: `.json()`, `.text()` and `.blob()`. Here is an example for the usage inside an API route.

```
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest) {
  const myJson = await request.json();
  // or: const myText = await request.text();
  // or: const myBlob = await request.blob();
}
```

Keep in mind that the request body can only be parsed once, otherwise you will encounter an error.